# ExternalProject_Add CONFIGURE_COMMAND can't contain double quotes

Tags: windows, openssl, cmake, 64-bit

I'm trying to use CMake to compile and build OpenSSL on a 64-bits Windows. Here is the code.

```
set(VS_ENV_SETUP "\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\\VC\\vcvarsall.bat\" amd64")
set(OPENSSL_CONFIGURE perl\ Configure\ VC-WIN64A)
set(OPENSSL_CONFIGURE ${VS_ENV_SETUP}\ &&\ ${OPENSSL_CONFIGURE})
set(OPENSSL_MAKE  ms\\do_win64a\ &&\ nmake\ -f\ ms\\ntdll.mak)

message(STATUS ${OPENSSL_CONFIGURE})
message(STATUS ${OPENSSL_MAKE})

ExternalProject_Add(openssl
PREFIX openssl
#-- Download Step ----------
SOURCE_DIR ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/ext/openssl
#URL ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/ext/openssl
#--Configure step ----------
CONFIGURE_COMMAND ${OPENSSL_CONFIGURE}
#--Build Step ----------
BUILD_COMMAND ${OPENSSL_MAKE}
BUILD_IN_SOURCE 1
#--install Step ----------
INSTALL_COMMAND ""} 
)

endif()
```

the message printed out indicates a set of double quotes warping around the filename of vcvarsall.bat, something like:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" amd64 && perl Configure VC-WIN64A
```

But when I put that command in ExternalProject_Add as an argument, it complains about

```
CMake Error at C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/ExternalProject.cmake:1032
(add_custom_command):COMMAND may not contain literal quotes: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
Studio 10.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" amd64  && perl Configure VC-WIN64A
```

If I don't double quoted the command, during building it won't be recognized as a whole command :(

What would be the solution or workaround?

Comment: I think you Visual Studio command needs to be set with `&quot;` becuase it uses XML escaping. So it would look similar to `&quot;C:\Program Files (x86)\...&quot;` You might have to quote that in double quotes. But I don't have something to test with at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to protect `*.bat` file, `VS_ENV_SETUP` is a list separated by `;` so it' okay like that:

```
set(VS_ENV_SETUP "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\\VC\\vcvarsall.bat" amd64)
```

#### BTW 1

You can use unix style directory separators to avoid endless `\\`:

```
set(VS_ENV_SETUP "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0/VC/vcvarsall.bat" amd64)
```

#### BTW 2

You can extend your `*_COMMAND` steps using `COMMAND` instead of `&&` (at least in this particular case):

```
ExternalProject_Add(
    ...
    # configure begin --
    CONFIGURE_COMMAND ${VS_ENV_SETUP}
    COMMAND perl Configure VC-WIN64A
    # -- end
    ...
)
```

Comment: @Jerry Nope, as much as you want: `CONFIGURE_COMMAND com1 COMMAND com2 COMMAND com3 COMMAND ...`